# Update Field in MongoDb of object to array of objects - command line

Tags: mongodb, command-line

I have a collection in MongoDB called Results

I have a field in the collection called Positions

```
"Positions": {
    "X": "1",
    "Y": "2"
}
```

I want to update this field to be an array of positions

```
 "Positions": [{
        "X": "1",
        "Y": "2"}, {X:"100", Y:"200"}]
```

I want to do this using the command line, is it possible? I have tried the following

```
use MyMongoDb
```

followed by

```
db.getCollection("Results").find( { "Positions" : { $type : 2 } } ).snapshot().forEach( function (x) {x.Positions = [ Positions ];db.jobs.save(x);});
```

I get an exception

> ```
> QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: TypeError: db.getCollection(...).find(...).snapshot is not a function :
> @(shell):1:1
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snapshot` is not a function of cursor says error stack... And it is right.

Anyway I propose you to use the following code

```js
db.getCollection("Results")
   .find( { "Positions" : { $type : 2 } } )
   .forEach( function(x) {
      x.Positions = [ x.Positions ];
      db.getCollection("Results").save(x);
   });
```

Please note that I have replaced
`x.Positions = [ Positions ]`
with
`x.Positions = [ x.Positions ]` as `Positions` variable is not declared.
And also `db.jobs.save(x)` with `db.getCollection("Results").save(x)` as I understood you wanted to update same collection.

I also would recommend to migrate depreciated `save` method to `update` or `replaceOne`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, the error is gone and the code execute but it just proceeds to a new line with the ">" character and the data did not change?

Comment: 1. Check if "Results" collection has documents for specified selector. For instance:
`db.getCollection("Results").find( { "Positions" : { $type : 2 } } ).count() 
`
should return anything greater than 0

Comment: 2. If you really don't have `_id` field on document replace `forEach` function with:
`function(x) { db.getCollection("Results").remove(x); x.Positions = [ x.Positions ]; db.getCollection("Results").insert(x);}`

Comment: the query returns 0? why is that?

Comment: There is a a _id field defined in the collection  "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e95b70fb54af5cb6ce49793"
    },

Comment: One note is thats using type 2 was wrong i needed to use type 3 as it is an object not a string

Comment: as you have _id field I propose you to replace `forEach` function with `function(x) { db.getCollection("Results").update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {Positions: [x.Positions]}});}`